# How to use wildcard in string matching

Tags: python, string

How can I do this:

```
if 'class="*word*"' in html:
    print "True."
else:
    print "False."
```

To use * as a wildcard char like in Linux?

Comment: And if you follow that trail, you'll realize that [you shouldn't be parsing HTML that way anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/102441)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to look at the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module. This will let you do a regular expression and accomplish the same thing as the * does in the linux command line.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to match Unix filename pattern matching, you can use the dedicated module [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html):

```
import fnmatch
words = ["testing", "wildcard", "in", "python"]
filtered = fnmatch.filter(words, 'p?thon')
# filtered = ['python']
filtered = fnmatch.filter(words, 'w*')
# filtered = ['wildcard']
```

If you want to do advanced pattern matching, use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression from the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module for general purpose pattern matching.

However, if you are working with HTML and trying to match tags and such I would recommend looking into [LXML](http://lxml.de/) and using its `parse` function and `cssselect` to get what you want.

```
from lxml import html

# read in and parse the html
html_doc = parse(filename).getroot()

# get elements that match class "classname"
elements = html_doc.cssselect(.classname)
```

[This doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) describes the different CSS Selectors